# How to connect Firebase using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, codeigniter-3

Is there any way to connect Firebase using Codigniter. Any libraries that used Firebase in codeigniter?

Answer (score 1):

Well CodeIgniter, while a stunningly cool PHP library, is still in PHP.
So why not use a simple [Firebase PHP client](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php)?
Looking at the manual, it seems like it will work quite nicely in a slick CodeIgniter code.

Comment: That is based on authenticating with a database secret  and  it is considered a legacy method in firebase .